# What does ? in output of ls -la mean?

Tags: mount, permissions, bind, ls

I'm having trouble with my webserver an noticed that the output of `ls -la /var/www` contains irregularily `?` instead of permission digits, e.g.

```
$ LANGUAGE=C ls -la /var/www/
ls: cannot access /var/www/dokuwiki: Permission denied
ls: cannot access /var/www/joomla: Permission denied
ls: cannot access /var/www/..: Permission denied
ls: cannot access /var/www/index.html: Permission denied
ls: cannot access /var/www/mediawiki: Permission denied
ls: cannot access /var/www/html: Permission denied
ls: cannot access /var/www/postfixadmin: Permission denied
ls: cannot access /var/www/awffull: Permission denied
ls: cannot access /var/www/index.lighttpd.html: Permission denied
ls: cannot access /var/www/drupal: Permission denied
ls: cannot access /var/www/sarg: Permission denied
ls: cannot access /var/www/.: Permission denied
ls: cannot access /var/www/trac: Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? .
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? ..
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? awffull
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? dokuwiki
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? drupal
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? html
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? index.html
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? index.lighttpd.html
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? joomla
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? mediawiki
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? postfixadmin
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? sarg
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? trac
```

`sudo ls -la /var/www` produces

```
$ sudo ls -la /var/www/
insgesamt 52
drwxr--r-- 11 www-data www-data 4096 Mai 17 23:37 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 root     root     4096 Apr 27 14:51 ..
drw-r--r--  2 www-data www-data 4096 Mai 12 15:34 awffull
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 Apr 21 23:55 dokuwiki
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 Apr 21 23:55 drupal
drw-r--r--  2 www-data www-data 4096 Apr  3 14:21 html
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  177 Apr 21 23:54 index.html
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 3568 Mai  1 11:13 index.lighttpd.html
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 Apr 21 23:55 joomla
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 Apr 27 18:58 mediawiki
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 Apr 21 23:55 postfixadmin
drw-r--r--  2 www-data www-data 4096 Mai 12 15:05 sarg
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 Apr 21 23:55 trac
```

which corresponds to the result of my `chmod` and `chown` invokations (after the problem occured). The directories dokuwiki, drupal, joomla, mediawiki trac are mount points (options `rw,bind`) of another partitions. I invoked `ls` with both mounted and unmounted directories. Everything worked like a charm on Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Which filesystem is /var/www? Smell as corruption. (By the way, prepending LANGUAGE=C to your command will give the messages in english like `LANGUAGE=C ls -la`). I would recommend a backup, unmount, and fsck the filesystem (in that order).

Comment: I think it's just because of the unusual `drwxr--r--` permissions on the top level `/var/www/` directory i.e. others are allowed to read but not execute the directory.  Execute permission is needed to stat the directory contents.

Comment: For the sake of completeness regarding the `LANGUAGE=C ls -la` command: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/473402/how-to-invoke-a-kde-application-with-another-language-equivalent-of-language-c/473456?noredirect=1#473456

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is caused by the fact that you don't have execute permission on the directories. Fix this by using `chmod o+x directory`. Make sure you don't make *files* executable unless you want them to be. It is not dangerous for directories to be executable. It only means you're allowed to traverse the directory.

Comment: Great, thanks! The solution was `chmod a+x` (I guess I'll have to do all operations on a backup again because permissions are messed up now), but at least I can `ls` my directory now :) Why doesn't `ls` fail and display such unclear output?

Comment: a+x and o+x is identical in that context, because the user and group owners already had it. I don't know exactly why you need the executable bit to see permissions, but permissions are irrelevant if you're not allowed to access the directory anyway. It's unusual to have read but not execute, although it is common to have execute without read.