# How to invoke a KDE application with another language (equivalent of LANGUAGE=C)?

Tags: gnome, kde, language-support

Invoking GNOME applications with `LANUAGE=C application` in a terminal seems to work fine (I've not yet experienced difficulties), I assume it is a specified (GNOME) behavior. What would be the equivalent way to controll language of KDE applications with a shell variable (not necessarily invoked in a KDE desktop, e.g. in Unity)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command

```
LANGUAGE=C application
```

is wrong. It may seem to 'work', but it's a coincidence.

```
LANGUAGE=X application
```

'works' too in that sense.

The `LANGUAGE` variable expects a colon separated list of language codes. Since neither C nor X is a valid language code, GNU compatible applications fall back to the original language, i.e. English.

```
LANGUAGE=en application
```

would be correct if `LANGUAGE` in the session environment is set to some other language, and you want to start a particular application in English.

To start non-GNU compatible applications in English you can use

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 application
```

Comment: `LANG=en_US.UTF-8 systemsettings` doesn't work for me.

Comment: @int_ua: Not for me either (on Ubuntu). `LANGUAGE=en_US systemsettings` changes some strings, but not all. Don't know if this is Kubuntu specific or systemsettings specific (or both).

Answer (score 2):

KDE 4:

```
KDE_LANG=de myapp
```

KDE Frameworks 5:

```
LANGUAGE=de myapp
```

See http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Localization/Building_KDE%27s_l10n_Module
Step 2: Test An Application

Comment: Thanks, `KDE_LANG=en_US` worked for `dolphin`, but it translated only panel buttons in `systemsettings`

Comment: KDE_LANG=a_locale works in the same way for dolphin/systemsettings or any kde4 application: translation of strings in gettext catalogs  are taken from the catalogs in a_locale if installed, translation of strings in desktop file are taken from the locale defined in systemsettings