# How to start Firefox in english on a german system without changing the langage settings?

Tags: firefox, language-support

I'd like to start Firefox in english in order to figure out a large amount translations of error messages without doing research. The usual suspects `LANGUAGE=en`, `LANG=C`, `LC_ALL=C` don't work.

I had trouble with this task for other programs, but the solutions don't apply here:

- [How to start ubuntu-software in english on a german system without changing the langage settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1131143/how-to-start-ubuntu-software-in-english-on-a-german-system-without-changing-the): The "solution" if you can call it that was to reconfigure the program with `dpkg` which doesn't help in this case
- [How to invoke a KDE application with another language (equivalent of LANGUAGE=C)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/473402/how-to-invoke-a-kde-application-with-another-language-equivalent-of-language-c): Firefox is not a KDE application

Afaik it'd be nice if `LANGUAGE` would work for Firefox since it's a comfortable reliable solution to overwrite the system-wide configuration for a single invokation of the program. I guess opinions on proposing its support as a feature doesn't go beyond the scope of this question.

I'd like to leave both the Ubuntu and Firefox settings untouched.

I'm using Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: @Jos I'd like to change the language temporarily without touching any settings. I clarified that in the question. Thanks for you input.

Comment: IIRC `/usr/bin/firefox` is a shell "wrapper" script rather than a binary executable; you may need to `export` the language/locale variables in order for them to propagate to the underlying process

Comment: @steeldriver I was successful with `export LC_ALL=C`, thank you. I'd accept that as an answer.

Comment: @steeldriver: No need to export anything to temporarily start FF in some other language. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LANGUAGE` variable is ignored by Firefox, but setting `LANG` or `LC_MESSAGES` should work.

- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
- Enter the kommand:

  ```
  env LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8 firefox
  ```